# Response.Redirect only refreshes page, does not redirect user to new page

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net, webforms

I have the following markup code for a button on my page:

```
<asp:Button ID="LoginButton" runat="server"
                                     CssClass="ButtonColor" 
                                     Text="Log In" 
                                     Width="75px" height="20px"
                                     OnClientClick="setCookie();"
                                     OnClick="LoginButton_Click"
                                     />
```

Here is LoginButton_Click:

```
    Protected Sub LoginButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    'Check if username / password is valid
    ' Dim gn = New BA_Shared_Object_Library.Data.SQLServer("GetNext 2.0 (DEV)", BA_Shared_Object_Library.Data.SQLServer.ConnectionConfigurationTypeEnum.DatabaseName)

    Dim CredentialsValid = Membership.ValidateUser(UserName.Text, Password.Text)

    If (CredentialsValid) Then
        'Add User Session stuff
        Session.Add("MFUserName", UserName.Text)
        Session.Add("MFPW", Password.Text)
        Response.Redirect("MFACheck.aspx", False)
    Else


    End If

End Sub
```

When this executes, I step through the code and hit the Response.Redirect line. However, instead of redirecting, the page just refreshes. What am I doing wrong?

I have tried `Response.Redirect("MFACheck.aspx", False)`

I have tried `Response.Redirect("~/MFACheck.aspx", False)`

What am I missing?

Thank you

Comment: Try `Response.Redirect("~/MFACheck.aspx", true);`.  See [Response.Redirect MSDN Reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a8wa7sdt(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: You probably get redirected back to the login page because you have not actually logged in the user. Either use the `FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage` method (which will create the auth cookie) or manually add the cookie using `FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie` before redirecting.

Answer (score 0):

Try Setting Response.Redirect to True

```
Response.Redirect("MFACheck.aspx", False)
```

If that is not the issue then make sure that when you are logging in you are using the correct credentials for the username and password.